# How to change the values of my array to "required"?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have this array:

```
Array
(
 [grp] => Array
     (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [firstname] => 5
                [lastname] => 
                [email] => 
                [username] => 
                [password] => 
            )
    ............
)
```

Expected out must be:

```
Array
(
 [grp] => Array
     (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [firstname] => required
                [lastname] => required
                [email] => required
                [username] => required
                [password] => required
            )
     ............
)
```

I have tried `array_walk` and `array_map` but it still give's me this output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [firstname] => required
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [lastname] => required
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [email] => required
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [username] => required
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [password] => required
            )
    )
```

Here's my code:

```
   $a = [];
   for($i = 1; $i <= count($count); $i++){
      $a[] = $count[$i];
   }

    function map($a)
    {
        $newArr = [];
       foreach($a as $key => $val)
       {
           $newArr[] = [$key => 'required'];
       }
        return $newArr;
    }

    function walk($a, $key)
    {
        $key = 'required';
       return $key;

    }

     print_r(array_walk($a, 'walk'));
     print_r(array_map('map', $a, $a));
```

Help me to get out of this situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array['grp'][1] = array_fill_keys(array_keys($array['grp'][1]), 'required');
```

If there's more than `[1]` in `$array['grp']`, loop:

```
foreach ($array['grp'] as &$values) {
    $values = array_fill_keys(array_keys($values), 'required');
}
```

Or, of course, `map`:

```
$array['grp'] = array_map(function (array $values) {
    return array_fill_keys(array_keys($values), 'required');
}, $array['grp']);
```

If you basically want to replace every *leaf* in an arbitrarily nested array, there's `array_walk_recursive`:

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$value) { $value = 'required'; });
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir @deceze. I'm a newbie in arrays. I used your second answer and it worked.

Comment: Why is the `array_walk_recursive` returning only number 1?

Comment: Because `array_walk_recursive` returns `true` or `false`...!? You don't really need its return value other than to check for possible errors.

Comment: Ahh. I see. So `array_walk_recursive` checks the value of `$array` from the map function?

Comment: That statement makes little sense. `array_walk_recursive` takes the array *by reference* and modifies it in place. It does not need to `return` it. The callback function also takes `&$value` *by reference* and modifies it in place.

Answer (score 1):

Use nested loops

```
foreach ($array as $i => $subarray1) {
    foreach ($subarray1 as $j => $subarray2) {
        foreach (array_keys($subarray2) as $k) {
            $array[$i][$j][$k] = 'required';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ( $array["grp"] as $key => $val ) {
   $array["grp"][$key] = "required";
}
```